# Avoid title tag on hover of an image due usage on a lightbox alike gallery

Tags: jquery, css, lightbox, alt

I'm using this lightbox gallery

http://www.no-margin-for-errors.com/projects/prettyGallery/

since it gaves me the chance of inputting
some html, as a difference of other lightbox
galleries (what I need is to show some facts
that i pull from a mysql query, and only with
the pretty gallery I could made a image shown,
as well as data below it... but to do so, I 
need to use some html... got my point?)

With this gallery, I could do so... but just 
using the title tag... and that is a problem,
as when I do some hover above the link/image,
the title pop's out... with all the html tags
(and besides it doesnt show nice, im not quite
sure about the seo effects...)

So now, what I would like to ask is:

a) how could I disable the hover of the
title & alt image, yet allowing it to
"survive" for the gallery (I try to 
disable it with jquery... but no success!!!)

b) I want to do things rightly... do you guys 
know any lightbox alike that could gave me 
"out of the box" customization for the caption 
below using html? (not through iframes, since 
im pulling data from the db, and im pulling
THAT precise row)

So basicaly, I firstly want to disable that
sideeffect of the usage of the title tag in
this lightbox... and in the meanwhile, I want
to know the existence of any gallery that allows
embedding html in a div rather in a title & alt
tag!)

Thanks in advance guys! Marlie.

Comment: By the way, id separate your two points into separate questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately the way the title tag is displayed is part of the html spec, and not really able to be styled, or disabled. You could use javascript to generate your own pop ups if necessary, and then youd be able to style them anyway you like.

Comment: Yeah, that was what I tought on first stage... strangely, it is possibly to disable it, but on general basis, with jquery. So thats why I guess its possible to avoid the hover effect. Any thoughts?

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you:

> http://www.dynamicdrive.com/forums/showthread.php?63914-Lightbox-image-viewer-2-03a-remove-hover-title

Basically, find the place where the lightbox script you are using pulls the caption from the title tag, replace that with "data-title" or something similar, and place the lightbox caption in that attribute ("data-title" that is). This frees you up to use "title" for whatever you want to show in the tooltip.